# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

I have an issue with selecting a method for a notification.

In the init I have definied this:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopSyncIndicator:) name:IOS_STOP_SYNC_INDICATOR object:nil];
```

The method is definied though, both in header and same implementation:

```
-(void)stopSyncIndicator
{
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

However when a different class is posting this notification:

```
NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:IOS_STOP_SYNC_INDICATOR object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
```

The hell breaks loose:

```
[FTRecordViewController stopSyncIndicator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d3bc00
2013-11-18 13:47:06.994 [1835:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FTRecordViewController stopSyncIndicator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d3bc00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01bf75e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018f88b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c94903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector has a `:` indicating it will accept an argument, your implementation does not

either

```
@selector(stopSyncIndicator) //no :
```

or

```
-(void)stopSyncIndicator:(NSNotification *)notification //accept argument
```

would fix this

Answer (score 2):

You telling that the observer's selector has a parameter:

```
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopSyncIndicator:) name:IOS_STOP_SYNC_INDICATOR object:nil];`<br/>
```

and your selector doesn't have a parameter:

```
-(void)stopSyncIndicator
```

To fix, either remove the `:` from `selector:@selector(stopSyncIndicator:)` or set your method signature to:

```
-(void)stopSyncIndicator:(NSNotification *)notification
```